# Install "Yum install httpd-devel" in a offline system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, offline, apache, redhat, yum

I'm trying to install "Yum install httpd-devel" in my system (RedHat/Fedora) but the system have no internet conection. I can download files from the internet and copy to the system, but I cant use internet on the system. I'm trying to install rails and i need " httpd-devel", " apr-devel" and "apr-util-devel".
For exemple, when i needed to use "gem install rails" I downloaded rails.gem and I used this file to install, there is a similar solution to my new problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just download the package and then install it using [rpm](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/rpm.8.html).

```
$ rpm -i [package-file]
```

Keep in mind that any package may require some extra dependencies, and you would need to download them all and install them by hand. It may get boring for packages with many dependencies.

To find the packages [rpmfind is your friend](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=httpd-devel): find the adequate package for your operating system (Fedora, Red Hat or whatever), download and check the dependencies. For example, [package for Fedora 18 x86_64](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/fedora/updates/testing/18/x86_64/httpd-devel-2.4.3-12.fc18.x86_64.html): you will need apr-devel and a few others. `rpm` will let you know if you are missing dependencies. Short of installing your own yum repository, you will have to download all dependencies by hand.

Comment: Where i can find this packages to download? I just went here http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache24 and tried to download " httpd-2.4.3.tar.bz2" and "httpd-2.4.3.tar.gz", but the program says that they are not packages. Sorry if it seens a dump question, i really dont understand much of it.

Comment: I have added an explanation, but googling for "rpm " + package name should be enough.

Comment: I still havent solved my problem. I cant find this package anywhere. I mean,Ii can find the link to download in may sites, but it turns out that those links are all broken

Comment: What is your version of Fedora exactly? For example for Fedora 18 I found this one: http://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/os/Linux/distr/fedora/linux/updates/testing/18/x86_64/httpd-devel-2.4.3-12.fc18.x86_64.rpm.

Comment: Thanks for your trouble alexinblue. I already found them. Now i having trouble instaling some dependecies. But I guess this is topic for other question. Thanks again for the help. :D

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help!